# CSS Reset of table border

Tags: css, html-table

I have a reset.css file that includes the following declaration:
`border:0 none;`

So when I make a table like this:

```
<table border="1">
```

The border does not show up.  How do I get the border to show up without removing the `border:0 none;` property?  The code must be `<table border="1">`.  Is there a way to make the table "ignore" the reset.css file? (This must work across all browsers as well including IE 6+)

Comment: Downvote for now marking an answer. Your question, as stated, was answered...

Answer (score 4):

Add a `style="border: 1px solid;"` to the `<table>` tag. Styles override attribute settings.

Comment: Hi,
It has to be border=1.  There's a section of the site that I can't use css declarations inline like that. Can I make that section ignore the border:0 none; property and just use browser default?

Comment: Why can't you use inline styles but you can use other inline attributes like border? Border isn't used anymore (as an attribute) because of CSS.

Comment: No because styles override any attribute settings there is no way to change it without using styles. You could use classes to differentiate the table types and have some without borders and some with. Using CSS selectors you can do some picking and choosing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so lets say you are in a jam, and lets assume:

- You can't do anything suggested above
- You can't use inline styles
- You can't add a style to your html doc like:

  ```
  <style type="text/css">
    table { border: 1px solid; }
  </style>
  ```
- You can't add a link to another stylesheet

Could you do something which is probably overkill, like use some javascript or jquery to do it?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var tableStyle = "table { border: 1px solid;}";

  function appendStyle(tableStyle) {
    var css = document.createElement('style');
    css.type = 'text/css';

    if (css.styleSheet) css.styleSheet.cssText = tableStyle;
    else css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tableStyle));

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
  };

  window.onload = function() { 
    appendStyle(tableStyle); 
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

directly after your reset css add a line like this:

```
table.borderIgnore { border:auto; }
```

then for your table do this:

```
<table class="borderIgnore" border="1">
```

let me know if that works